# What does KEYEVENTF_SILENT equate to

Tags: c#, pinvoke

KEYEVENTF_SILENT is a constant used in calls like this one:

```
keybd_event(VK_OFF, 0, KEYEVENTF_SILENT, 0);
keybd_event(VK_OFF, 0, KEYEVENTF_SILENT | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

But since I am using .net I don't know what the actual value of KEYEVENTF_SILENT is.  I can't call it with out knowing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve these issues, you should look at WinUser.h.

It comes with Visual C++ and with the Windows SDK (which is free), and can be found in the Headers folder.

Comment: I have Visual C++ but I never use it.  I have no idea where the Headers folder is.  Does it have a common location?

Comment: Somewhere in the installation directory.  Search for `WinUser.h`.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v5.0\Include`

Answer (score 2):

Ah.  Found it right after posting.

```
    public const byte VK_OFF = 0xDF;
    public const byte KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
    public const byte KEYEVENTF_SILENT = 0x0004;
```